# Q: How can I get dldt buildinfo?

Tags: openvino

I am able to get opencv's build info via `getBuildInformation()`, is there a way to get dldt's build information?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting this answered on [opencv/dldt github](https://github.com/opencv/dldt/issues/427), I am linking to that to let others see the discussion.

For Python, have a look at "object_detection_sample_ssd.py" (dldt/inference-engine/ie_bridges/python/sample/object_detection_sample_ssd/object_detection_sample_ssd.py); it produces logs about (the plugin's)version and build info.